# How to setup factory album for nested json values

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch data from REST API with nested items. JSON structure looks like:

```json
[
    {
        "userId": 0,
        "title": "",
        "items": [
            {
                "name": ""
            }
        ],
        "cardData": {
            "name": ""
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to create a model for this. I am not sure how album should look here for these two objects. Can someone give me advice?

```dart
  final int userId;
  final String title;
  final List<Item> items;
  final CardData cardData;

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      title: json['title'],


    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO you'd better create a model that fits your use case instead copying/pasting a model that comes from an external API.

That being said, if you do want to have a Dart model that maps your REST API, what you can do is:

```dart
  final int userId;
  final String title;
  final List<Item> items;
  final CardData cardData;

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      title: json['title'],
      items: json['items'].map((item) => Item.fromJson(item)).toList(),
      cardData: CardData.fromJson(json['cardData'])
    );
  }
```